# What dynamical properties should we expect from systems satisfying statistical ones?

Tags: pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, st.statistics, ergodic-theory

Some results on probability theory can be generalized to more abstract ones in ergodic theory, for example:

- the strong law of large numbers can be seen as a particular case of Birkhoff's ergodic theorem;
- there are some systems $T:X\to X$ that admit a convenient invariant measure $\mu$ that satisfies the Central Limit Theorem: for every function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ of a specific type, the limit $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} \mu\left\{x\in X \mid \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^{k}(x)\leq c\right\}=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{c}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}dx,$$ holds for every $c\in \mathbb{R}$ (here $\sigma$ is a convenient constant). See [this post](https://vaughnclimenhaga.wordpress.com/2013/03/17/spectral-methods-3-central-limit-theorem/) for more details.

On the other hand, is not unusual to obtain dynamical properties of the systems when one already knows that it admits an ergodic measure, for example (if $X$ is a regular enough metric space, $T$ is continuous, and the invariant measure $\mu$ is ergodic, then $T$ is transitive when restricted to the support of the measure).

**My question is:** can we respect something from the dynamics if we already know that the system satisfies some form of the Central Limit Theorem?